# Installing rqt_graph in ROS2 Dashing

Tags: ros, ros2, rqt-graph, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install rqt_graph for ROS2 to visualize the ROS nodes and the computation graph.
I have ROS2 dashing installed in the docker (using the Autoware.Auto class/tutorial)
After entering ade and sourcing the setup.bash in Autoware.Auto, I use the following command:

**sudo apt-get install ros2-dashing-rqt_graph**

and I get the following error:

**Unable to locate package ros2-dashing-rqt-graph**

Could anyone help me out here? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368930/installing-rqt_graph-in-ros2-dashing/) by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is called `ros-dashing-rqt-graph`.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on 2021-01-07**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-01-07**:
Please remember to mark this as the solution (check mark).